# Modifying VirtualBox GUI to use kchmviewer if available

Tags: c++, qt, g++, virtualbox, c-preprocessor

**Note**: I would like to point out that I have no C/C++ knowledge, but I know `bash` so please try to provide functional solutions over language specific explanations. Thanks for that.

For better clarity, I'm going to separate my question into two distinct sections:

## 1.)

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
if (system("which kchmviewer > /dev/null") == 0)
{
    // "which kchmviewer" exit code 0
    #define USE_KCHMVIEWER 1
}
else
{
    // "which kchmviewer" exit code 1
    #define USE_KCHMVIEWER 0
}
```

**Explanation**: Check, *at runtime*, whether `kchmviewer` is available in the operating system, and if yes, set `USE_KCHMVIEWER` to "1" (true), otherwise "0" (false).

## 2.)

I would like to place the above code into the VirtualBox codebase, then use it instead of `VBOX_OSE` in the following cases:

**a.)** in `UIMessageCenter::sltShowHelpHelpDialog()`, line containing `#ifndef VBOX_OSE` will be replaced with `#ifdef USE_KCHMVIEWER`;
**b.)** in `UIMessageCenter::sltShowUserManual()`, line containing `# ifndef VBOX_OSE` will be replaced with `# ifdef USE_KCHMVIEWER`;
**c.)** in `VBoxGlobal::helpFile()`, line containing `# if defined VBOX_OSE` will be replaced with `# if !defined USE_KCHMVIEWER`.

```
// File: VirtualBox-5.0.6/src/VBox/Frontends/VirtualBox/src/globals/UIMessageCenter.cpp

void UIMessageCenter::sltShowHelpHelpDialog()
{
#ifndef VBOX_OSE
    /* For non-OSE version we just open it: */
    sltShowUserManual(vboxGlobal().helpFile());
#else /* #ifndef VBOX_OSE */
    /* For OSE version we have to check if it present first: */
    QString strUserManualFileName1 = vboxGlobal().helpFile();
    QString strShortFileName = QFileInfo(strUserManualFileName1).fileName();
    QString strUserManualFileName2 = QDir(vboxGlobal().homeFolder()).absoluteFilePath(strShortFileName);
    /* Show if user manual already present: */
    if (QFile::exists(strUserManualFileName1))
        sltShowUserManual(strUserManualFileName1);
    else if (QFile::exists(strUserManualFileName2))
        sltShowUserManual(strUserManualFileName2);
    /* If downloader is running already: */
    else if (UIDownloaderUserManual::current())
    {
        /* Just show network access manager: */
        gNetworkManager->show();
    }
    /* Else propose to download user manual: */
    else if (cannotFindUserManual(strUserManualFileName1))
    {
        /* Create User Manual downloader: */
        UIDownloaderUserManual *pDl = UIDownloaderUserManual::create();
        /* After downloading finished => show User Manual: */
        connect(pDl, SIGNAL(sigDownloadFinished(const QString&)), this, SLOT(sltShowUserManual(const QString&)));
        /* Start downloading: */
        pDl->start();
    }
#endif /* #ifdef VBOX_OSE */
}
…
void UIMessageCenter::sltShowUserManual(const QString &strLocation)
{
#if defined (Q_WS_WIN32)
    HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow(), strLocation.utf16(), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, NULL);
#elif defined (Q_WS_X11)
# ifndef VBOX_OSE
    char szViewerPath[RTPATH_MAX];
    int rc;
    rc = RTPathAppPrivateArch(szViewerPath, sizeof(szViewerPath));
    AssertRC(rc);
    QProcess::startDetached(QString(szViewerPath) + "/kchmviewer", QStringList(strLocation));
# else /* #ifndef VBOX_OSE */
    vboxGlobal().openURL("file://" + strLocation);
# endif /* #ifdef VBOX_OSE */
#elif defined (Q_WS_MAC)
    vboxGlobal().openURL("file://" + strLocation);
#endif
}

// File: VirtualBox-5.0.6/src/VBox/Frontends/VirtualBox/src/globals/VBoxGlobal.cpp

QString VBoxGlobal::helpFile() const
{
#if defined (Q_WS_WIN32)
    const QString name = "VirtualBox";
    const QString suffix = "chm";
#elif defined (Q_WS_MAC)
    const QString name = "UserManual";
    const QString suffix = "pdf";
#elif defined (Q_WS_X11)
# if defined VBOX_OSE
    const QString name = "UserManual";
    const QString suffix = "pdf";
# else
    const QString name = "VirtualBox";
    const QString suffix = "chm";
# endif
#endif
    /* Where are the docs located? */
    char szDocsPath[RTPATH_MAX];
    int rc = RTPathAppDocs (szDocsPath, sizeof (szDocsPath));
    AssertRC (rc);
    /* Make sure that the language is in two letter code.
     * Note: if languageId() returns an empty string lang.name() will
     * return "C" which is an valid language code. */
    QLocale lang (VBoxGlobal::languageId());

    /* Construct the path and the filename */
    QString manual = QString ("%1/%2_%3.%4").arg (szDocsPath)
                                            .arg (name)
                                            .arg (lang.name())
                                            .arg (suffix);
    /* Check if a help file with that name exists */
    QFileInfo fi (manual);
    if (fi.exists())
        return manual;

    /* Fall back to the standard */
    manual = QString ("%1/%2.%4").arg (szDocsPath)
                                 .arg (name)
                                 .arg (suffix);
    return manual;
}
```

## Bottom line

***How to achieve this?*** My operating system is [Trisquel 7.0](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=trisquel) (GNU/Linux).

Thank you for the advice.

**P.S.**: More details can be found in [this forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=73979).

**P.P.S.**: As I don't know yet how to rebuild only specific parts of the source code, trying your solution will most likely require from me to recompile the whole application before I can check whether it works or not. This may take an hour or more so please be patient.

**UPDATE**: Rephrased the question to reflect my findings. This time I'm trying to be as specific as possible.

Comment: If making such a small change *"will probably require recompiling the whole application [which] may take an hour or more"* then 1) your code is overcoupled and 2) your build system was designed by Rube Goldberg.

Comment: **@LightnessRacesinOrbit**: Because I have to. I haven't received help from the developers so I'm trying to do this myself.

Comment: Do you want to check for `kchmviewer` at build time, or at run time?

Comment: **@Beta**: This is because I don't know how to recompile only the part that I have changed. It may be possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: **@Beta**: run time.

Comment: @mYself `if (system("which kchmviewer") != 0)` might not return the value you expect, see the [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system).

Comment: @mYself: Oh, then you'll have to rewrite the program. We're really not going to be able to satisfy you with an answer until you've learnt the language. Do you have a friend who can take on this task for you?

Comment: If you use `system("which kchmviewer")` (and I don't know a better way offhand) you'll have to capture the *output* of the operation, not just the *return value*, which is a pain. After that, it's pretty easy.

Comment: **@LightnessRacesinOrbit**: Answering your now deleted question: I don't know how to do this at the build system level. What I'm trying to do is to adapt the VirtualBox code so when I try to open the documentation inside the GUI, the program will to check whether `kchmviewer` is available in the system, and if it is, open the CHM doc, otherwise the PDF one.

Comment: **@Beta**: I guess I only need the exit status but I have no idea how to "capture" that to EXIT_STATUS_OF_WHICH_KCHMVIEWER. Any idea?

Comment: `QProcess::startDetached` returns `false` if command failed. So you can try launch `kchmviewer`. If it fails you can use `pdf`. It still requires changing  `sltShowUserManual` to have both file names (`pdf` and `chm`).

Comment: **@OrestHera**: I've previously tried removing the #if, #else, #endif directives while leaving only the `name` and `suffix` pointing to VirtualBox.chm. This worked and the GUI opened VirtualBox.chm in kchmviewer provided that it was installed, otherwised dropped an error message to stdout. So I would like to adapt only the part of code mentioned in my initial post here.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted everytime I ask some real-world question instead of a more popular one? I know this question is way too specific but I honestly don't know where else should I ask.

Comment: If you remove `#if-else` only in `helpFile()`, but in `sltShowUserManual` the function `vboxGlobal().openURL("file://...);` is used for `chm` when the system cannot open it you will have an error. However, you can run `kchmviewer` by `QProcess::startDetached()`. In that case if you receive `false` go to `vboxGlobal().openURL("file://...);` with `PDF` document.

Comment: **@OrestHera**: I understand, I just tried not to make a change in another file if not absolutely necessary. I understand what I have to change in `helpFile()`, but I'm not quite sure how to do the rest in `sltShowUserManual`. I know what to do, just not how to write it yet. I'll write back as soon as I figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: **@πάντα ῥεῖ**: Sorry for my late reply. Currently, I don't understand the syntax on that page but I'll try to investigate whether this will allow me to dynamically define the exit status of kchmviewer in EXIT_STATUS_OF_WHICH_KCHMVIEWER, so I can use that in the `#if` statement.

Comment: Exit code of `which` you can get from `QProcess::exitCode()`. It can be also checked that `kchmviewer` is launched successfully by the return value of QProcess::startDetached().

Comment: **@Orest Hera**: I forgot to ask about this, thank you for repeatedly pointing this out. :) I'll post my question below your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your last forum post with `system("which kchmviewer")` is almost correct. You only need the declaration `QString name, suffix;` above the `if` and skip `const QString` in the `{}` blocks. However, it is a solution only for Linux, since `which` does not work on Windows.

Since your project uses Qt you can use `QProcess` to check the exit code of the `which` command if such command exits:

```
QString name = "UserManual";
QString suffix = "pdf";

if (QProcess::execute("which kchmviewer") == 0)
{
    // "which kchmviewer" exit code 0
    name = "VirtualBox";
    suffix = "chm";
}
```

That is for your function `helpFile()`.

However you can try directly launch `kchmviewer` by `QProcess::startDetached()` in `sltShowUserManual()`. The return value of `startDetached()` is `false` if it fails. In that case you can go to default behavior using `pdf`.

Comment: Can either of `QProcess::startDetached()` or `QProcess::exitCode()` be used to check if kchmviewer is available in multi-platform way? I does not intend to compile VirtualBox outside of GNU/Linux but I prefer making changes that are not written in a platform-specific way provided that they're simple enough.

Comment: @mYself I updated the answer by simpler `QProcess::execute()`. It works as `system`, however the return value of that function is clearly defined http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute However, it is still only for Unix, since it calls `which`. `QProcess::startDetached()` can be used for multi-platform solution, however I'm not sure that you want to run `kchmviewer` on Windows.

Comment: No, I does not intend to use this on Windows. I only proposed that because I intend to publish a set of commands that will build VirtualBox with specific changes, and I does not want to prevent others from building the program on other platforms.

Comment: I tried your suggestion from the first paragraph and the compilation passed the modified C++ file. As this will take a some time, I'll write back after I properly test all the different solutions you've proposed and look around on the Internet for explanations. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply but I haven't noticed the time when I wrote back yesterday and I had to go to sleep. Now that I recompiled VirtualBox several times to check the behaviour of different solutions, I have realized that I made some mistakes: „**1.)** I forgot to redirect the output of `which kchmviewer` to `/dev/null` (works with `system()` but not with `QProcess::execute()`); **2.)** You were right about `sltShowUserManual()` that I also need to change otherwise `kchmviewer` outputs everything to stdout, which isn't the expected behaviour; **3.)** I also need to change `sltShowHelpH…

Comment: …elpDialog()` not to try to download the CHM documentation if not available.” As this seems to be overly complex, I would like to know whether it is possible to simply define something like `USE_KCHMVIEWER` globally, and use that instead of `VBOX_OSE` where needed.